# What is a consistent way to provide a huge file over samba?

Tags: backup, samba

On my server I've a large zip-file which has to be backup in regular manner. A samba-fileshare running on the server provides the necessary platform to do so. From there the backup will be retrieved from an other server.

**Issiue:**

One time at a day I'm going to renew this file with a cron-job. While I'm copying my huge file to the samba-directory, inconsistent reads may occur from the backup-server.

To solve this problem I came up with several ideas:

- shutdown samba for the time I update the zip-file
- delete file, then renew file.
- work with symlinks to make the change as fast as possible
- change file permissions of the copied file as long as I'm copying the file so it's not seen by samba

**Is there a canonical way to provide consistent files via samba while updating them?**

Comment: Use `rsync` to copy the file to the samba directory, it uses a temporary name and renames once complete.

Comment: A common aproach to this problem in general (although not canonical) is to write the file under a different name and then move it to its target location (e.g. `mv -f file target`). Depending on what suits your application better it can be sensible to truncate the file upon starting the copy (`: > target`).

Comment: thank you for your advice. I'll figure something out! Good to know that this is a real issue and I don't see ghosts in being overcautious. =)